context.go() not removing navigation stack (Flutter Web)
When I come back from second screen to home screen, It should be not possiblity to come back to second sreen by back button in home screen.
Actually when I tested it by using only browser's back button in step 2, It's working fine.

Click "Go to the second screen"
Click "back to the Home screen"
By clicking browser's back button I can come back to Second Screen

Tested on go_router: ^14.1.3
When I come back from second screen to home screen, It should be not possiblity to come back to second sreen by back button in home screen.
Actually when I tested it by using only browser's back button in step 2, It's working fine.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());

}

final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/',
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      name: 'home', // Optional, add name to your routes. Allows you navigate by name instead of path
      path: '/',
      builder: (context, state) => HomeScreen(),
    ),


    GoRoute(
      name: 'second', // Optional, add name to your routes. Allows you navigate by name instead of path
      path: '/second',
      builder: (context, state) => SecondScreen(),
    ),

  ],
);


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Constructs a [MyApp]
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: _router,
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Home Screen')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => context.go('/second'),
          child: const Text('Go to the second screen'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondScreen({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Second Screen')),
      body: PopScope(
        canPop: false,
        child: Column(
          children: [
             ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => context.go('/'),
                child: const Text('back to the Home screen'),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


There is a error with GoRouter and CanPop. Here below is a table from the issues on GitHub that explains it deeper, where 'Expected' column is stating if the behavior is expected or not. Downgrading to a 12.0.0 version should solve the issue for now. Also remember to use onPopInvoked since they are supposed to be used together and not separately for most constant behavior
Edit: Added code with proper use of onPopInvoked to showcase how it works

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/',
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      name: 'home', // Optional, add name to your routes. Allows you navigate by name instead of path
      path: '/',
      builder: (context, state) => const HomeScreen(),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      name: 'second', // Optional, add name to your routes. Allows you navigate by name instead of path
      path: '/second',
      builder: (context, state) => const SecondScreen(),
    ),
  ],
);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Constructs a [MyApp]
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: _router,
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Home Screen')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => context.go('/second'),
          child: const Text('Go to the second screen'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondScreen({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Second Screen')),
      body: PopScope(
        canPop: false,
        onPopInvoked: (didPop) {
          if (didPop) {
            print('Did pop');
          } else {
            print('Did not get to pop');
          }
        },
        child: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => context.go('/'),
            child: const Text('Back to the Home screen'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


I've downgraded and it didn't help at all

I just used your code and version for go_router: 12.0.0 works and stops the pop. Make sure to run 'flutter clean', 'flutter pub get', and 'dart run build_runner watch -d' (If you don't have path for dart set up replace dart part with 'flutter pub').
Changed code is in the answer above

strange, still doesn't work. What flutter version do You have?

I use version 3.22.1 here
